# Is there any way to log http requests/responses using Selenium Webdriver (firefox)?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

Is there any way to log http requests/responses using Selenium Webdriver (firefox)?

I guess it's possible to drive web traffic through proxy and log it, but maybe there is more simple "internal" selenium solution?

Asked this question on #selenium channel:

> > > **you will need to proxy it to capture the requests**

so, looks like only way to setup proxy for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Now year 2021, answer is: **YES**.

you can use the new lib:  [selenium-wire](https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire)

## How to use `selenium-wire`

### install

`pip install selenium-wire`

### change code

change from

```py
from selenium import webdriver
```

to

```py
from seleniumwire import webdriver
```

### add your code

after `driver.get(yourUrl)`, add:

```py
# Access requests via the `requests` attribute
for request in driver.requests:
    if request.response:
        print(
            request.url,
            request.response.status_code,
            request.response.headers['Content-Type']
        )
```

can got your expected `request` and `response`.

Comment: Hi, is there something similar for Java?

Answer (score 3):

No, WebDriver doesn't have any methods to examine or modify the HTTP traffic occurring between the browser and the website. The information you've already gotten from the Selenium IRC channel (likely even from a Selenium committer) is correct. A proxy is the correct approach here.